# with open equivalent for variables in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with heavy memory-consumption datasets and wonder if there is any equivalent to

```
with open('file.txt','rb') as f:
    print f.read()
    #<more possible code on f>
```

which opens the file inside the `with` context and closes it later, in general variables and in particular in `pandas`.

I would expect that the following code will make the calculations and dump the dataframe `df` from the memory:

```
with pd.read_csv('data.csv') as df:
    print df.head()
    #<do calculations of df>
```

Is there any equivalent solution?

Comment: Try to execute the following search: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=python+pandas+context+manager&oq=python+pandas+context+manager&aqs=chrome..69i57.10475j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may not be the most elegant way of getting what you desire (given that this could been implemented inside `pandas`), but I believe it gets the job done. What it is trying to do is that it creates a class called `DFrameManager` whose main existence is to provide `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. These methods happen to be what makes the `with_statement` work. The class will have an attribute `df`, which is the dataframe you are importing. Further, the `__enter__` will return `self`; while the `__exit__` has one job: delete the dataframe (`self.df`). This means that you can do whatever you wish to do with the dataframe inside the `with_statement`. Once you get out of the `with_statement`, the `__exit__` method will take care of the deletion of the dataframe for you.

The following should be a decent starting point:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


class DFrameManager:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[-1].lower()
        if 'xls' in file_extension:
            self.df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        elif 'txt' in file_extension:
            self.df = pd.read_table(file_path)
        elif 'csv' in file_extension:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("File types other than xls, xlsx, txt and csv need to be implemented first")
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        del self.df


with DFrameManager("data.csv") as manager:
    print(manager.df.head(1))
```

This only prints the first row of the dataframe, but the possibilities should be endless.

If I try to access the dataframe, I get an `AttributeError`.

```
print(manager.df)
```

returns

> AttributeError: DFrameManager instance has no attribute 'df'

This, in essence, means that you should not have that dataframe in memory anymore, as soon as you exit the `with_statement`. The garbage collector dealt with it when the `__exit__` method called `del self.df`.

I hope this helps.